# Incorporate uncertainty of position to my result

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis

The data is a list of measurements of power $P_i$ with estimated uncertainty $\Delta P_i$ and another list with measurements of positions $x_i$ and estimated uncertainties $\Delta x_i$. All the $\Delta x_i$ have the same value. It looks like a Gaussian distribution and I want to find its FWHM.

I have heard of the method of least squares. For this I just need fit function (Gaussian), the $P_i$, the $x_i$ and the $\Delta P_i$. The problem is that I do not know how to use the uncertainty in position with this method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not mathematically simple, and if you're not already familiar with the least square method, it might be a bit overwhelming. A least square regression with uncertainties both in the independent and dependent variables is frequently called [*Total Least Squares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares).

In addition to the linked Wikipedia article, you can find the theory and further references in the following guide (available from the National Physical Laboratory, UK, upon free registration), section 4.3 *Generalised distance regression (GDR)*:

R M Barker, M G Cox, A B Forbes and P M Harris, [*Discrete Modelling and Experimental Data Analysis*](http://www.npl.co.uk/publications/discrete-modelling.), NPL Report DEM-ES 018, 2007.

Several software tools like SciPy, Matlab, etc. have functions that perform this kind of regression with minimum effort. I invite you to search the documentation of your favourite tool to find which functions are available.

Comment: Thanks, I  found out the Python library Scipy has it very nicely implemented. On [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126884/python-scipy-odrpack-odr-example-with-sample-input-output) there is some example code.